# Why is EF added to a project with new Razor page

Tags: visual-studio, razor-pages, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-3.0

Why is EF added to a project when adding a razor page. This is a new project, no auth or authorization, no contexts, no databases. Plain Jane. It runs when built. However, add a new Razor page and the scaffolding adds two EF packages.

I can delete them, build and run with no issues. Is it a carryover bug or am I missing a dependency somewhere? Add a page, it's going back in.

Packages are:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

To repro - this is what I add doing:

1 - right-click folder, add Razor Page

2 - Provide name, add

There's no EF mention, no CRUD selection, nothing of the sort. Using statements on generated page does not include EF namespaces.

Unless I am missing something, somewhere, seems like a bug

***Updated to VS 2019 16.3.1 <- fixed the issue***

[image]
[image]

Comment: Add a page how? If those packages are part of the template you used, they'll be added every time

Comment: Scaffolding is done with EF, I believe. Just add a page without scaffolding.

Comment: That's what I am saying - this project has no references to anything EF - not even Identity. There's no reason for EF packages to be added while scaffolding a Razor page.

Comment: @BradPatton - you're saying that the scaffolding itself requires EF? Like it's pulled from some internal SQL database and it needs it to do it's job? So it's dev dependency?

Comment: @TonyBasallo How are you adding the page? All the options I look for 'scaffolding' mention Enitity Framework in the UI. You should be able to easily add a razor page. Scaffolding takes a model and generates CRUD pages for that model.

Comment: Fixed in the latest path release. 16.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed in VS 2019 16.3.1, released yesterday.